# How to access hello world Java microservice through Gateway or Ingress in Istio on Minikube/Windows? I've been stuck for hours/days/weeks

Tags: istio

Minikube version: v0.25.2

Operating Syatem : Windows 10 Enterprise

```
Kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.1", GitCommit:"4ed3216f3ec431b140b1d899130a69fc671678f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-05T16:46:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-10T12:46:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.99.100:8443

istioctl version
Version: 1.0.4
GitRevision: d5cb99f479ad9da88eebb8bb3637b17c323bc50b
User: root@8c2feba0b568
Hub: docker.io/istio
GolangVersion: go1.10.4
BuildStatus: Clean
```

Tried to run simple hello-world application through Istio on above environment.

```
kubectl get services
springbootapplication   NodePort    10.103.103.141   <none>        80:30456/TCP   3d

kubectl get pods
springbootapplication-v1-6b5bdff8cd-2qhnn   2/2     Running   5          3d
```

After that I create one below helloworld.yaml file and run the command `kubectl apply -f helloworld.yaml`. It runs successfully.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: springbootapplication
  labels:
    app: springbootapplication
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: http
  selector:
    app: springbootapplication
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springbootapplication-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: springbootapplication
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: springbootapplication
        image: springbootapplication:v1
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: springbootapplication-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: springbootapplication
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - springbootapplication-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /home
    route:
    - destination:
        host: springbootapplication
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: springbootapplication
spec:
  host: springbootapplication
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
```

Problem: I don't know how to access this Spring Boot application now? How to get Gateway IP and Ingress?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have exposed this as an http service, so in your kubernetes cluster, check for 'istio-ingressgateway' service (it should be a load balancer) and check the endpoint which is exposed at port 80.

Or, through command line, try these.

kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].nodePort}' --> should give you the ingress port

minikube ip  --> should give you IP.

Comment: error: error executing jsonpath "'{.spec.ports[?(@.name==http2)].nodePort}": unrecognized identifier http2

Comment: it should be in double quotes. Did you try "http" as well?

Comment: What happens if you access the istio-ingressgateway? Did you verify the results of kubectl get gateway and kubectl get virtualservice commands ?